# hexagon shadow css javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have this hexagon

```
<some code here>
```

[codepen Example](http://codepen.io/yanisKondakov/pen/pNvEoO)

How i can add this element shadow?

The result will looks like this
[Result Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNOYY.png)

Comment: I really dont know why this question is minused, but i spend a lot of time to get final result. http://codepen.io/yanisKondakov/pen/PbwRzw

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the CSS3 `box-shadow` property. For example:

```
[your hexagon] {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

Comment: I know about *-shadow properties. I actually don't know how to get hexagon shadow on exactly this example.